# ¿Cómo hacer un regex para validar que los dos elementos consecutivos no sean signos aritméticos?

Tags: java, regex

Quiero que al ingresar una cadena como esta:

```
5+4+4+3+2++*
```

Detecte cuando haya signos juntos para después procesar la información como error.

Hasta ahorita tengo un regex pero no funciona bien, a veces sí se activa (muy pocas) y la mayoría de las veces no pasa nada.

Regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d*$
```

**UPDATE**

Ya encontré la forma de hacer el regex, pero ahora cuando lo implemento en java ya no me lo activa.

```
String allTexto = "";
allTexto = txtS.getText().toString();
if (allTexto.matches("[\\+\\*\\-\\/]{2,}")) {
    Log.i(null,"Error");
}else {
    Log.i(null,"No error");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para validar si mar de un operador esta puedes usar `.*[\+\*\-\/]{2,}.*`, el cual evalúa si alguno de los caracteres dentro de los `[]`  se repite 2 o mas veces de forma consecutiva

**Actualización**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class JavaFiddle
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      String allTexto = "";
  allTexto = "5+4+4+3+2++*";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[\+\*\-\/]{2,}.*");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(allTexto);
  if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("Error");
  }else {
      System.out.println("No error");
  }
    System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcciones:

- Dentro de una clase de caracteres, no es necesario escapar los caracteres especiales. Solamente el `-` tiene un significado especial, pero no si va al principio o al final. Para que coincida con un operador, alcanza con `[-+*/]`.
- Si se busca validar que coincide con 2 *o más* (`x{2,}`), significa que basta con que coincida simplemente con 2 ocurrencias (`x{2}`).
- El método [String.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) sirve para comparar si *todo el texto completo* coincide con una expresión regular. Para comparar en cualquier parte del string, se usa [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

Expresión regular:

```
[-+*/]{2}
```

Código:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

```java
String allTexto = "5+4+4+3+2++*";

String regex = "[-+*/]{2}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(allTexto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Tiene más de un operador consecutivo. '" + matcher.group() + "' aparece en la posición " + matcher.start());
} else {
    System.out.println("No tiene operadores consecutivos");
}
```

Resultado:

```
Tiene más de un operador consecutivo. '++' aparece en la posición 9
```

Demo:
https://ideone.com/iEqPYo

---

Pero esto aún permitiría que un usuario ingrese espacios entre cada operador, por lo que podemos validar con:

```
String regex = "[-+*/] *[-+*/]";
```

Y, aún así, deja lugar a que ingrese algo como `*4/`. Y para eso, podemos validar todo el string, asegurándonos de que sea una sucesión de números separados por operadores:

```
String regex = "^ *\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?(?: *[-+*/] *\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?)* *$";
```

- `^` - coincide con el inicio del texto.
- `*` - cualquier cantidad de espacios.
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` un número, opcionalmente con decimales, opcionalmente con exponente de notación científica.
- `(?: *[-+*/] *\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)*` es un grupo que está repetido 0 o más veces. Coincide con:

  - `*[-+*/] *` - un operador, que puede tener espacios alrededor.
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` un número.
- `*` - más espacios opcionales.
- `$` - coincide con el fin del texto.